# Cannot set attribute for entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

Please explain the reasons for this strange behaviour of Core Data.
I have Entities: "Messages" with Attributes:
id – integer 64
body – String
updated – integer 64

I execute the following code:

```
// Insert new message
long now = [date timeIntervalSince1970]*1000L;   
m = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:self.privateObjectContext];             
[m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:msg.id] forKey:@"id"];  
NSLog(@"id=%ld", [[m valueForKey:@"id"] longValue] );  
[m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:now] forKey:@"updated"];  
NSLog(@"updated=%ld, now=%ld", [[m valueForKey:@"updated"] longValue], now );
```

In debugger I see:

> id = 16603952
>   updataed=0, now=1459769138535

Why I can not set updated Attribute?

P.S. XCode 7.2.1

Comment: Is the code and debug information above copied and pasted exactly? Your debugger output has a spelling mistake but the code doesn't. If you copy and paste exactly then it ensures people are looking at the exact misbehaving code

Comment: I have been programming on the Apple MacBook, and write to the forum via Windows PC. Therefore possible some lapse :)

Comment: ... because `updated` is a property of the `NSManagedObject` class, so you should not use it as an attribute name.  Change the name of the attribute to something different.

Comment: Many thanks!! I rename attribute "updated" to "tupdated" and it worked!   I have never reed in the Core Data documentation  about prohibited attribute names. :\

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks!!
 
I rename attribute "updated" to "tupdated" and it worked!

I have never reed in the Core Data documentation about prohibited attribute names. :\